# Extract from and to from POSIXct columns based on recurring conditions

Tags: r

How could I get the start and end date from a POSIXct column field for the first and last entries of state 'Dry' for the table below.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Timestamp = as.POSIXct(
    c(
      "2021-07-30 19:00:00", "2021-07-30 19:30:00", "2021-07-30 20:00:00",
      "2021-07-30 20:30:00", "2021-07-30 21:00:00", "2021-07-30 21:30:00",
      "2021-07-30 22:00:00", "2021-07-30 22:30:00", "2021-07-30 23:00:00",
      "2021-07-30 23:30:00", "2021-07-31 00:00:00", "2021-07-31 00:30:00",
      "2021-07-31 01:00:00", "2021-07-31 01:30:00", "2021-07-31 02:00:00",
      "2021-07-31 02:30:00", "2021-07-31 03:00:00", "2021-07-31 03:30:00",
      "2021-07-31 04:00:00", "2021-07-31 04:30:00", "2021-07-31 05:00:00",
      "2021-07-31 05:30:00", "2021-07-31 06:00:00", "2021-07-31 06:30:00",
      "2021-07-31 07:00:00", "2021-07-31 07:30:00", "2021-07-31 08:00:00",
      "2021-07-31 08:30:00", "2021-07-31 09:00:00", "2021-07-31 09:30:00",
      "2021-07-31 10:00:00", "2021-07-31 10:30:00", "2021-07-31 11:00:00",
      "2021-07-31 11:30:00", "2021-07-31 12:00:00"
    )
  ),
  State = rep(c("Dry", "Wet", "Dry", "Wet", "Dry"), c(6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L))
)
```

The expected output is given below

```
data.frame(
  From = as.POSIXct(c("2021-07-30 19:00:00", "2021-07-31 02:00:00", "2021-07-31 10:00:00")),
  To = as.POSIXct(c("2021-07-30 21:30:00", "2021-07-31 05:30:00", "2021-07-31 12:00:00"))
)
```

I tried group by using dplyr but not sure how to proceed further, the tried code is given below

```
library(dplyr)
sms_data %>% 
  group_by(State)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could assign each set of *dry* and *wet* an increasing integer value exploiting the integer structure of `factor`. Then, using `by`, split and apply `range`, `rbind` and convert `as.POSIXct`, finally `cbind` state column with help of `rle`.

```
> by(dat$Timestamp, cumsum(abs(c(0, diff(as.integer(as.factor(dat$State)))))), range) |>
+   do.call(what='rbind.data.frame') |> lapply(as.POSIXct) |> as.data.frame() |>
+   setNames(c('from', 'to')) |> cbind(state=rle(dat$State)$values)
                 from                  to state
1 2021-07-30 19:00:00 2021-07-30 21:30:00   Dry
2 2021-07-30 22:00:00 2021-07-31 01:30:00   Wet
3 2021-07-31 02:00:00 2021-07-31 05:30:00   Dry
4 2021-07-31 06:00:00 2021-07-31 09:30:00   Wet
5 2021-07-31 10:00:00 2021-07-31 12:00:00   Dry
```